# Multiple filters on RecyclerView

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

In this app , The transactions are to be filtered first on the basis of period (month-year) which is coming from a fragment and the second filter i want is to filter (on the basis of transaction type i.e credits only) using switch.

Currently i have both the filters working individually , but i cannot figure out how and where to get the filtered list updated in the recyclerview after the first filter and apply second filter on it.

As of now when i apply first filter and then perform second filter , the list of recyclerview is original list instead of the month filtered list .

**On clicking a button in this activity , fragment is opened and from there i retrieve the month selected using interface that has method passDataToActivity()**

Activity with recyclerview and switch :

```
public class TransactionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCommunicator{

    SearchView searchtrans;
    SearchView searchView ;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Button monthButton, filterButton;
    public static RecentTransAdapter mAdapter;
    private Switch aSwitch;
    boolean filtered;
    public FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
    String dateSelected ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transactions);

        searchtrans = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchTrans);

        searchtrans.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.trans);
        List<Transaction> newList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        newList = Transaction.transactionList;

        monthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.monthButton);
        // filterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
        aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        String currentMonth = "" ;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      /*  Date date = new Date();
        cal.setTime(date);
*/
        currentMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(cal.getTime());

        monthButton.setText(currentMonth);

        monthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                // FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                MyFrag dFragment = new MyFrag();
                // Show DialogFragment
                dFragment.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");
//                fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment(mAdapter);
            }
        });

        **mAdapter = new RecentTransAdapter(newList, this);**

        **aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new** CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

                if (!isChecked) {
                    Log.d("notchecked","yo");
                    mAdapter.getFilter().filter("");

                } else {
                        mAdapter.getFilter().filter("credit");
                }
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        });

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

     @Override
public void passDataToActivity(String someValue,RecentTransAdapter recentTransAdapter) {
    dateSelected = someValue;
    //dateSelected = "someTest";
    monthButton.setText(dateSelected);
    mAdapter = recentTransAdapter ;
}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: declare one method and override it when you initialize your adapter in fragment.

Comment: you can use it as like interface

Comment: sorry bud , didn't quite get you there , i guess the issue you can see is the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on switch is in onCreate method , which takes adapter with `newList` which is the original list in activity , so i need a way to get the updated list instead of original , right ?

Comment: i tried passing updated adapter from fragment to activity in the method `passDataToActivity` , i updated the code ^ , if that's what u are trying to say , but it does not give the required behaviour